# The headers are difficult to read on ELL mobile chat

Tags: bug, status-completed, chat, design, mobile-web

The pale blue page background isn't contrasting enough with the white text, particularly when it's plain text. The bold lettering ("all rooms") is easier to read but might still be helped by a different color. I like the *idea* of the white but "mine", "all", and "favorite" just don't separate out from the blue well enough and "invited" and "site" are borderline.

[image: ELL Chat room selection page in iOS]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Should be much more readable now:

> [image]