# Top bar of mobile chat is hardly readable for some site(s)

Tags: bug, design, chat, mobile-web

The top bar of the mobile chat pages has a background matching one of the colors in the site's design. For some sites, like [Aviation](https://aviation.stackexchange.com), a light background color has been chosen which makes the white text very hard to read ([link](https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=aviation.stackexchange.com)), at least on Safari for iOS:

[image]

There might be more sites suffering from this problem (potentially all 70+ sites with a custom design); for English Language Learners it has already been [solved](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/288197/295232) by making the text black instead of white. That would be a good solution for Aviation as well.